# the meaning of "hunt for" similar to "look for" in the sentence I mentioned

Tags: phrasal-verbs

If your dog were lost, would you say "I'll hunt for my puppy."? It sounds odd to me though dictionaries all say that "hunt for" is similar to "look for" in the meaning.
Thanks a lot for answering me:)

Comment: You'd search for your puppy (I hope if its lost, you find it!) :-)  Did your dictionary search show "search" as a synonym?

Comment: Hunt is generally used  when you are looking for an  animal which doesn't want to be  captured,  (usually a wild animal like  a fox  for instance) . I guess your puppy is looking for you too, instead.

Answer (score 1):

"*Hunt for* X" means search for X; it does not mean "*hunt* X".

"*Dig for* X" does not mean "*dig* X".

"*Play for* X" does not mean "*play* X".

etc.